# vueJS как вывести variant_id из моей ссылки

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, liquid

Подскажите как вывести значение variant_id= из ссылки

пример ссылки : http://mysite.ru/link?variant_id=196388417

Но нужно именно в vueJS, так как вывести нужно без div=id, а в формате {{ proid }}

Начала моего кода, но дальше не получается :

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '.app',
  data: {
    proid: 0,
  },
  methods: {
    splitlink() {
      this.proid = this("http://mysite.ru/link?variant_id=196388417".split("=")[1]);
    }
  },
});
```

```html
<div class="app">
{{ proid }}
</div>
```

Может, это можно сделать и без vueJS, но не знаю как, только начинающий я :(

Мне данный вариант нужен, так как использую liquid, и мне необходимо присвоить значение без тэгов html

Помогите кодом, спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно запустить метод `splitlink`, чтобы получить результат. Для этого можете воспользоваться хуком [mounted](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted):

```
mounted() {
    this.splitlink()
  },
```

Ваш код в рабочем виде (обратите внимание из кода удалено непонятное использование контекста `this` как `this(...)` )

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '.app',
  data: {
    proid: 0,
  },
  methods: {
    splitlink() {
      this.proid = "http://mysite.ru/link?variant_id=196388417".split("=")[1];
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.splitlink()
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div class="app">
  {{ proid }}
</div>
```